# Query Picasa Web Albums for specific PhotoIDs to check for existence

Tags: google-api, picasa

I have a list of PhotoIDs as well as the User ID which apparently is required as PhotoID is not globally unique, and I'm attempting to get a list of photos in order to test whether the photos are still accessible.

The closest I've found so far is here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-picasa-data-api/photos$20by$20id/google-picasa-data-api/OzLyJOVpd4M/7xiSPB4Tg9YJ which mentions the following query should get me there:

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/?kind=photo&v=2&fields=entry[gphoto:id=1234 or gphoto:id=4567]&prettyprint=true
```

However this doesn't appear to work, even when used with photos I know to exist, I either get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'/>
```

Or if I specify a valid access_token I get the following, despite the token working fine for more basic queries of unlisted photos.

```
Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get querying single gphoto:id work using the following:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&v=2.0&fields=entry[gphoto:id=5833637579580309538]
```

However as soon as I attempt to use `||` (as suggested below) I get an error such as:

```
Invalid selector expression at position 35: no viable alternative at character '|'
```

If I use " or " as alluded to in the Google API Documentation, it simply ignores all but the first `gphoto:id` return only 1 row.

**UPDATE 2**

Actually it looks like the following DOES work, however not for all photos:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&v=2.0&fields=entry[gphoto:id=5827988830283069682%20or%20gphoto:id=5812362364496750642](gphoto:id)&prettyprint=true
```

Is there some sort of permissioning that prevents some photos from being directly query-able?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use '||' instead of 'or' in the request. I was able to select multiple photos in an album with this request.

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/{albumid}?kind=photo&[gphoto.id={photo1 id}||gphoto.id={photo2 id}]
```

Comment: Sorry that just gives me a list of all photos in the album. I'll update the question to include my latest findings, I've managed to get querying a single ID as working.